# СПП с придаточным сравнительным?

Tags: спп, синтаксический-разбор

В пойму речки Черевинки залетают мины и снаряды, словно куропатки стайками фыркают.

Расчлененная структура? Придаточное сравнительное.
Верно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, расчлененная структура, придаточное сравнительное.